# how to stop crontrack sessions

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, iptables, netfilter

I have router with linux system based. I have the related SDK to customize the linux system of the router.

When I disable a port forwarding from iptables rules, the running crontack sessions do not go down and keep established.

I want to stop all running crontack sessions when I disable a port forwarding from iptable rules. I mean, only remove the crontack sessions related to the removed rule. So stop all crontack sessions with dest IP (lan IP) = the dest IP of removed rule.

How to do that in kernel space? how to develop a kernel module that go over all crontack session and check the destination IP and remove only the session with a given ipaddress? are there some link for that?

Otherwise are a user space way ( C functions or Linux commands) to stop specific crontack sessions ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/nf_conntrack-sysctl.txt

> `nf_conntrack_tcp_loose - BOOLEAN
>
>       0 - disabled
>       not 0 - enabled (default)
>
>       If it is set to zero, we disable picking up already established
>       connections.`

So the already established connection is detected on-the-fly (without SYN/SYN+ACK/ACK involved) and added back as a new conntrack entry. Since it's a new conntrack entry, the nat table will be traversed again and the DNAT rule applied again. Even if one way doesn't work immediately (if there's no SNAT/MASQUERADE defined in addition to the DNAT rule the http server's outgoing packets might appear on WAN as 192.168.3.17 for a short while and be rejected/ignored by 192.168.33.13), as soon as the other way tries again (ACK retry from 192.168.33.13...) this will match.

Type this:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_loose
```

And try again deleting the conntrack entry with `conntrack -D` ...

This should hopefully prevent a new conntrack entry to be created and cut the download.

**This answer is copied from:** https://superuser.com/questions/1258689/conntrack-delete-does-not-stop-runnig-copy-of-big-file